# Laravel validation errors empty on AWS Elastic Beanstalk with 3 instances

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, laravel-5.7

So I have this laravel 5.7 application running on AWS Elastic Beanstalk with multiple instances (3 instances). The issue is when validating a form if there is an invalid input the form is not submitted but the validation errors are not returned back or it's empty. Im using laravel [Form Request Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#form-request-validation)

My Session driver is the database.

Everything is working properly on my local machine but when uploaded on AWS EB this issue occurs. Is there any configuration that I need to do?

Thanks in advance.

**Controller code**

```
 public function store(CustomRequest $request) 
{ 
   // code here
}
```

**CustomRequest code**

```
class CustomRequest extends FormRequest {
    public function authorize()
    {
        if(Sentinel::check()) {
            return true;
        } 

        return false;
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required',
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'name.required' => 'The name field is required.',
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Is sticky session enabled on your server?

Comment: @VidhyutPandya you mean on the load balancers? should i enable it? okay. i will try. THanks

Comment: @VidhyutPandya I have enabled the sticky session on load balancer but still no success. Any other idea? Thanks